# Check if Image file name exists php loop

Tags: php, image, loops

I have multiple images on my root folder `/images/filename.here`. Image filenames are like this (email): `me@yahoo.jpg`, `me@yahoo_1.jpg`, `me@yahoo_2.jpg`, `you@gmail.jpg`.

My code on showing only one image of user if exist `me@yahoo.jpg` and `you@gmail.jpg`:

```
<? 
$email= $data['payment']['email'];
$receipts = "images/".$email;
     if (file_exists($receipts)) { ?>
                <img src="<?=($receipts)?>" width:"100px" height="50px"/>
                <? } else {
                    echo "no receipt";
    } ?>
```

this only show the "without `_x`" filename. How can I show other images of a user(e.g me@yahoo) using loop `_1` ,`_2`, `_3`... It should display all images that belong to a user.

Comment: Create a while loop with a counter, if the counter is 0, then $filename = $email , if its more than 0, then $filename = $email."_".$counter. If the filename doesn't exist then exit the while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a helper function `get_image` to return the path of the image by email and index, and use a while loop to build the list of images:

```
<?php
function get_image($email, $i) {
    $path = "images/receipts/".$email;
    if ($i > 0) $path .= '_' . $i;
    $path .= '.jpg';
    if (file_exists($path)) return $path;
    return null;
}

$i = 0;
while ($path = get_image($email, $i)) {
    echo "<img src=\"$path\" width:\"100px\" height=\"50px\"/>";
    $i++;
} 

if ($i == 0) {
    echo "no receipt";
}
?>
```

Comment: Just need some changes here. Thanks anyway.